# SQL Delete rows based on query from same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this query :

```
SELECT cur.`id`
FROM `current` AS cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(EndDay_id.id) as id, EndDay_id.server_id
    FROM current as EndDay_id
    GROUP BY server_id, gameday
    ) AS EndDay
ON cur.id = EndDay.id
WHERE EndDay.id IS null
```

How do I delete the rows from table 'current' whose id field is in the resultset of previous query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE cur FROM `current` AS cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(EndDay_id.id) as id, EndDay_id.server_id
    FROM current as EndDay_id
    GROUP BY server_id, gameday
    ) AS EndDay
ON cur.id = EndDay.id
WHERE EndDay.id IS null
```

I tested it and this should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a47c81

Comment: #1109 - Unknown table 'current' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what this means. I updated my answer now. Can you try "DELETE cur" instead of "DELETE `current`"

Comment: managed to simplify things a bit, based on both your answers.
DELETE current
FROM `current`
LEFT OUTER JOIN .....

Answer (score 0):

```
delete current
where id in (SELECT cur.`id`
FROM `current` AS cur
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(EndDay_id.id) as id, EndDay_id.server_id
FROM current as EndDay_id
GROUP BY server_id, gameday
) AS EndDay
ON cur.id = EndDay.id
WHERE EndDay.id IS null)
```

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'current' for update in FROM clause